# How can i get firewall rules for a sql server in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I run the following in powershell

```
 Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName <myRG> -ServerName <myServer>
```

But get the error

```
 Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule : The term 'Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

Is there a module i need to install ? How can i get this going ?

Comment: SQL Server is not a firewall and has no rules.  SQL Server you can specify the Port number and can specify a certificate that is used to make a connection.  Firewalls work by blocking port numbers.  Protocols have standard port numbers.  Firewall blocks the port numbers.  Virus checkers check contents of connection.  If you cannot connect to a SQL Server than you have to debug the connection issues.  One thing you can do is to check if your firewall is blocking the port number for SQL Server.  If you cannot connect to SQL Server than check log file with SSMS with explorer under Management.

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule` cmdlet is part of the [`Az.Sql` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/?view=azps-9.4.0).

```
(Get-Command -Name Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule).ModuleName

Az.Sql
```

You might want to make sure this module is installed with the appropriate version.